# Excel formula to find 2 different values in the same cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, vlookup

attached you will see 2 images, on one side, I have the "company" and the article in the same line.

First sheet source

[image: First sheet source]

Meanwhile , in the other sheet, i have the company in one column and the article in the row.

Second sheet ie result

[image: Second sheet ie result]!
The idea is to have a formula to fill the second sheet , in the example I did it manually.

So far I tried to combine count*find , but got no solution.

thank you !!

I tried count*find, but run out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a concatenated vlookup. If your data is in A9-1:13, you put put this formula in the first cell of your table and drag accross and down.

```
=IF(ISTEXT(VLOOKUP($A2&" "&B$1,$A$9:$A$15,1,FALSE)),"ok", "x")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `G2`:

```
=TOCOL(IFS(B2:E4="ok",A2:A4&" | "&B1:E1),3)
```

**Note**: In case your company contains spaces in their names I do believe that a choice for a different delimiter could be a wise one. Hence the use of the pipe-symbol.

---

If I read the question wrong and you need to actually return the table from given delimited values, then try:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(G2:G7,A2:A4&" "&B1:E1),"ok","x")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using <kbd>COUNTIFS()</kbd> with wildcard operator `*`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,"*"&$C2&"*",$A$2:$A$7,"*"&D$1&"*"),"ok","x")
```

---

Or use <kbd>MAKEARRAY()</kbd> to spill

[image]

---

```
=IF(MAKEARRAY(ROWS(C2:C4),COLUMNS(D1:G1),LAMBDA(r,c, 
 COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"*"&INDEX(C2:C4,r)&"*",A2:A7,"*"&INDEX(D1:G1,c)&"*"))),"ok","x")
```

---

Another alternative :

[image]

---

```
=IF(SUM((TEXTBEFORE($A$2:$A$7," ")=$C2)*(TEXTAFTER($A$2:$A$7," ")=D$1)),"ok","x")
```

---

Here is the other way round, if so then

[image]

---

```
=TOCOL(IF(D2:G4="ok",C2:C4&" "&D1:G1,p),2)
```

---

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand well but it seems the question was to create the second sheet from the first one and not the other way round

Comment: yes they have two sheets where in the first sheet, OP have company name with the article and in the other sheet company in the column and article in the row, so they _idea is to fill the second sheet_ also sorry for the delay in replying my computer is facing some problem so had to restart again

Comment: You need to get A2:A7 from C1:G4 not vice versa.

Comment: Nice one, even though it was intended the other way around. I like the TOCOL version best. I'd use IFS though.

Comment: @P.b Sir agreed, !